# Filter the data viewed using properties value in firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have Firebase data structure like this :

```
hotelboard
 Events
     -K09Iy9pa6FEA0rmmEMH
        emailId:"said@gmail.com"
        images
            0:"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEU"
        post: "This is event 1"
        title:"Event 1"

 Facilities
     -K09Ibsqz5L82PUoCEjY
        emailId: "said@gmail.com"
        post: "this is fac 1"
        title: "Facility 1"
 Offers
     -K09IipPdR7We_D5Tzb9
        emailId: "said@gmail.com"
        post: "this is offer 1"
        title: "Offer 1"
 Restaurant
     -K0O-kIJASIhOa_gWKWY
        emailId: "said1@gmail.com"
        post: "sdgsdgsdgasdasdasdd"
        title: "sdgsgsdgsdg"
```

And I'm adding the Event, Restaurant, Offers and Facilities by dropdown list from form.

Before I implement my app this way, I could filter the data in the view by the emailId which is equal to the login username that the user can view just his post when he log in, this way :

```
var url = "https://hotelboard.firebaseio.com/";
var fb = new Firebase(url);

var fbObj = fb.startAt($scope.username).endAt($scope.username); 

$scope.articles = $firebaseArray(fbObj);
```

and iterate the Array in my view.

But after I made this implementation with the structure over , the code over not working anymore .

I don't know how to query my data in the way I wanted to view. I found a lot of information that shows that I can use

```
fb.child("Event").startAt........
```

But I don't want to write the `child("child_name")....` I wanted that its taken dynamically how is it in the structure.

Please help and thank you in advance ...

**SOLVED UPDATE**

I followed **JAY** advice and i add a user node which give every user a unique ID and under the ID i pushed my data.
So my data structure look like this now :

```
hotelboard
  users
    0affbcbd-e29a-4b44-9036-e2086fb8d51e
      Events
        -K0YGDwJ4xgBjYql-39W   +

        -K0YGL7ziuRh-IioF8yC
           emailId:"said@gmail.com"
           post:"This is post 1"
           title:"Post 1"
     Facilities   +
     Restaurant   +
   19cc2166-6b1f-4ef9-8586-0735c6d92a4e
     Events       +
     Offers       +
     Restaurant   +
```

After in my controller i filtered the data that every user can just vew his own posts

```
var fbObj = fb.child("users/").orderByKey().equalTo(fbAuth.uid);
```

Thanks for the advice **JAY**

Comment: It's not clear what you want exactly: When you say, 'the user can view just his post when he log in', does that mean when the user logs in they should be able to see Events, Facilities etc that contain his email? If that is the case, the structure won't allow queries as they are one level too deep (see deep path queries in the latest update). Also a suggestion, disassociate the emailId from the post: what if the user changes email? That can be solved by having a /users/ node with each user having a userId (a randomly generated id) that you can then use to associate each entry with that user.

Comment: @Jay i want the user to view only his own post. Before i was using `startAt() , endAt()` which use ".priority"which i add in my post creation method. if you take look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029200/select-specific-item-and-view-it-in-modal-to-update-into-firebase-using-angularj you can see my code.  I read the deep path querying in the last update , but there they write the path self `ref.orderByChild("dimensions/height").on....`  i want that the path taken dynamically

Comment: There still some ambiguity to the question in that all four nodes have 'post' children. Are you wanting to retrieve the 'post' within Events, Facilities, Offers, Restaurant?

Comment: Where is the relationship between users and posts defined? For that matter, where are the posts? Neither of these things are in the sample data. What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I followed **JAY** advice and i add a user node which give every user a unique ID and under the ID i pushed my data. So my data structure look like this now :

```
hotelboard
  users
    0affbcbd-e29a-4b44-9036-e2086fb8d51e
      Events
        -K0YGDwJ4xgBjYql-39W   +

        -K0YGL7ziuRh-IioF8yC
           emailId:"said@gmail.com"
           post:"This is post 1"
           title:"Post 1"
     Facilities   +
     Restaurant   +
   19cc2166-6b1f-4ef9-8586-0735c6d92a4e
     Events       +
     Offers       +
     Restaurant   +
```

After in my controller i filtered the data that every user can just view his own posts

```
var fbObj = fb.child("users/").orderByKey().equalTo(fbAuth.uid);
```

Thanks for the advice **JAY**